# How to rename variable when renaming class

Tags: eclipse, refactoring

Is there a way to rename all occurrences of `X x` to `Y y`. When I rename X to Y using Eclipse refactoring option I get `Y x`. The idea is to rename the variable name if its name is the same as the class renamed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the tool Refractor > Rename on your variable x. All occurrences of x will be renamed.

1. Select your variable
2. Click on the right button
3. Refractor > Rename

Comment: That's will rename the variable only in the current function/class. I want to do it in all the classes where I used the class X.

Comment: I think it is not possible to do it properly. There is no link between the name of your variable and your class in all your classes.

Try to search in your project "X x" and replace with "Y y". But it is not convenient and dangerous.

Comment: No there's a link they have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

select your variable then:    `Alt-Shift-R`